# why i am not able to edit or create system variables in windows?

Tags: environment-variables, system-variable

I was trying to set the GRADLE_HOME system variable for my system as per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joc8A2mKb7g) in youtube. I am admin user and only user in my system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mylBN.png)

This image is screenshot from my desktop. As you can see that **I am not able to create or edit the system variable**.

can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you click new?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser The New that isn't greyed out is the one for User variables - not for System variables.  My question is why it needs to be a System variable.  Unless the variable will be used by a service or some other context where no one is logged in there is no reason a User variable won't work.

Comment: Related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/cant-edit-environment-variables-in-windows-10/29ca1561-5c4d-4c0d-ab93-808411a062a3

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I can edit the environment variables. What I am saying is that I am not able to create a new system variable. You can see in that youtube video that he was able to edit the system variable but I cannot. I think it might be the issue with the registry or group policy settings of windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the windows key and type env, the first result should be "Edit the system environment variables". Clicking on that should bring you straight to "System Properties" where you can click on "Environment Variables..." in the bottom right corner. There you should be able to change system variables.

Or you can run regedit and the variables are in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Answer (score 4):

(Win+X -> Y), going to "Advanced system settings", then clicking "Environment Variables". select system variables that properly launches the edit window and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might benefit someone like me that's why posting, So what is happening is when we are searching "env" it is showing up "Edit the system environment variables" dialog box directly where we cannot edit the system variables but only user variables. Search for the keyword "advanced system settings" and it will show up the System properties dialog box and then you can click on environment variables button at the bottom right which will open the correct dialog box for changing the system variables as well.

[image: Search result in windows]